# Calculates the Average Score of Given Number of Scores in C

Tags: c

I have started with C and I made this code and as the title suggests this program can calculate the average score of a given number of scores. Now my major concern is, is it more efficient to get the number of scores as a Command Line Argument or is the current approach better incase if sometime in the future someone designs a Interactive Front-End for it?

Also I am using the cs50 library I am not sure if it is allowed here please tell me if it's not so I'll keep that in mind in the future.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
float average(int length, int array[]);

int main(void)

{
    int i, j;
    printf("This Program will Help you Compute the Average Score \n");         //Welcome Message
    int Total = get_int("How Many Scores do you wish to Use: ");               //Asks User for How Many Scores
    int scores[Total];                                                         //Stores Scores in an Array
    for (i=0; i < Total; i++)                                                  //A Loop to keep Asking for Scores
    {
        scores[i]=get_int("Enter Score %d \n", i+1);                           //i+1 is used as it would be better to start asking from Score 1 so that it avoids confusion
    }
    printf("The Average score is %f", average(Total, scores));
}

float average(int length, int array[])
  {  int sum = 0;
    for (int j=0; j < length; j++)
    {
        sum += array[j];
    }
    return sum/(float)length;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reduce the number of loops

The most time-consuming part of your program is to loop through the array. Notice that you have done this twice, why can't you keep a track of the total sum while taking the input?

```c
#include <stdio.h>  

float average(int sum,int number);

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_integers,number,sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of integers: ");
    scanf("%d",&number_of_integers);
    for(int i = 0;i < number_of_integers;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        sum+=number;
    }
    printf("Average = %d",average(sum,number_of_integers));
}

float average(int sum, int number)
{
    return sum/(float)number;
}
```

This reduces the number of loops from `2` into `1`. And completely removes the need of having an array of integers. Making your program both memory efficient and fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot understood :) Also this is probably the best welcome I have ever received on any SE so many upvotes

Comment: i just checked you github profile and man you learnt coding at such a young age can you refer to some resources which you used? I am totally new to coding

Comment: Thanks a lot as a side question how long did it take you to master C++? I am studying C as I was following the cs50 course and they started with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113926/discussion-between-foundabettername-and-aryan-parekh).

Comment: "The most time-consuming part of your program is to loop through the array." --> The most time consuming is the execution of complex functions like `scanf()` and `printf()`, dwarfing the concern about using a separate `average(int length, int array[])`.  Better to focus on reducing O(n) ( which  was done here with memory usage) than concerns about "number of loops from 2 into 1"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What if the size of the input is `100,000`, would having 2 loops instead of 1 still be minimal compared to `printf()`?

Comment: Having 2 loops vs 1 would not impact the time performance.  I/O still dominates.  There are still `n` i/o calls.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what ??!. OP's code already has `n` I/O calls, plus another iteration through the array to get the average, how will removing the second loop completely not make a difference?

Comment: [Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) the 2 approaches.  Even with automated input the time spent will be 1.000000 vs 1.000001 of the other - no practical difference.  With the knitted approach here, code does have a memory savings, yet now pieces are intertwined and not readily available for code re-use as separate modules. Code re-use is the valuable asset in long term effective programming.

Answer (score 1):

> ... major concern is, is it more efficient to get the number of scores as a Command Line Argument or is the current approach better in case if sometime in the future someone designs a Interactive Front-End for it?

"more efficient" needs to focus on **[order of complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)**, else one wastes valuable coding effort in [premature optimizations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/94903).  OP's code run-time is O(n).  It does not get better in run-time using using 1 loop or 2.

> current approach better incase if sometime in the future someone designs a Interactive Front-End for it?

Current is better.

Code architecture **designed for growth** is a good idea.  A good strategy is to separate input, processing and output.

In OP's small code, loops can be combined (saves memory), yet for growth and real larger code, and portability, maintain separations.

```
// Pseudo code
main()
  setup()
  input()
  process_data()
  output()
  cleanup()
```

Set aside small linear time improvement concerns and look to proper **full range functionality**

- Below code can readily overflow `sum += array[j]`.
- `float` in C is rarely the preferred  type.  Use `double` and reduce precision loss.
- Array sizing best done with `size_t`.
- Consider [future trends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features) with function signatures (which OP followed with `length` 1st).
- Use `const` when referenced data is not changed.  Allows wider usage and conveys intent.
- Consider alternatives to casting.
- Trust your compiler to make at least basic optimizations.  Code for clarity.

OP's

```
float average(int length, int array[]) {  // length more than INT_MAX?
  int sum = 0;
  for (int j=0; j < length; j++) {
    sum += array[j];  // Overflow ?
  }
  return sum/(float)length; // low precision FP
}
```

Alternative

```
double average(size_t length, const int array[]) {
  long long sum = 0;  // or double sum = 0.0 is very large input expected.
  for (size_t j=0; j < length; j++) {
    sum += array[j];
  }
  double avg = sum;
  return avg/length;
}
```

**Minor: Output improvements**

`"%f"` is weak.  Consider `"%g"`.  It is more informative when the value is smaller and not so noisy when the value is large.

No need for spaces before `"\n"`.  Such spaces are surprising to find in output.  Avoids surprising effects.

```
// Enter Score %d \n"
Enter Score %d\n"
```

Comment: I performed your `get_average()` *1000000* times, with the size of the array as 1000. The input of the method being the same, your code slowed down a lot whereas my solution had the sum pre-calculated so **it was instantaneous**. I am really confused because I'm sure you have way more knowledge than me, can you explain?

Comment: @AryanParekh `average()` is only called once in OP's code.  Why call 1000000 times?  Looks like you are trying to assess different `average(size_t length, const int array[])` versus different `main()`. Profile the whole, not the pieces.

Comment: I really think that is a bad excuse, But, What about memory?  It is extremely in-efficient if you look into it form that side

Comment: You are hanging on the exception that the `get_average()` function will be called only once as the question does the same, yet you talk about long term code re-use

Comment: @AryanParekh "I really think that is a bad excuse" --> Perhaps your insight into programming exceeds mine .  Re: memory in-efficiency.  Answers already covers that with "saves memory".  Coding to optimize trivial programs prevents larger concerns about code re-use.

Comment: please tell me *larger concerns about code re-use*, that are completely worth trading with memory and speed.

Comment: @AryanParekh These excess concerns about performance neglected the _functional_ error in your code. `printf("Average = %d",average(...` should have been `printf("Average = %g",average(.. ` and is part of the larger concerns.  Your valuable programmer time needs to be spent in various ways.  Code correctness comes first before optimizations.

Comment: @AryanParekh With OP's narrow usage it is true the O(1) memory is needed and not O(n).  Processing data as it arrives is good for these select issues.  Should code expand and re-used to cover other statistics like mode and sort, O(n), or more, is needed.  It is likely the problem is already O(n) memory as `n` is known _a priori_.   Further your speed assessment lacks a fair compare as the compare done in your input code is not counted (it too takes time) whereas OP's compare in the read loop is 0 (as it is not there).

Comment: My speed assesment lacks no fair, it's you that refuse to believe it as being fair. You agree that your function **will be much slower**, your only argument is that it is fine if the function is slow as it is only being called once, and hence it does not make a difference. As for the measuring part, I have used **the same** input and output for both test cases. Plus their time isn't considered because I measured using an external library where I could place the start and end points carefully. This should end at, "we both think differently", 

Comment: Just to point out, as you say "should code expand".Is there no possibility that `average()` can be called more than once if the code *expands*? The time taken for your average function at best is `O(n)`. Due to the design of my function, it can even be inlined if it's called frequently having a clear advantage.

Comment: @AryanParekh Given you have comment _after_ "This should end at", I'll add one.  Consider a more pragmatic approach to solving differences.  Look for common ground rather than incite.  You have decades of programming in front of you and good programming involves teams.  Our differences in advice are not that far apart.  What is optimal is involves many more aspects than what is presented here and so depending on those, the optimal path for OP could go left or right.

Comment: I agree with you 100% on this, I think our argument boils down to what the code is actually being used for. Currently, I am working on my chess engine, spending 24 hours to create a single, CPU-efficient function, and then another 24 hours to optimize it even more.If the purpose was different, then my approach would be different too. Possible that your coding style is different than mine,  I'd say it's similar to how some people loathe OOP and other's don't. Opinions‍♂️

Comment: @AryanParekh My first big program was for 2 to play chess - and not cheat.  I even had en passant checking, check, checkmate and castling - almost.  My castling checked if the king, rook had never been moved by that color and nothing in between, king not in check, not across check or into check.  The corner case missed was: "is the rook there"  (i.e. it could have been taken/moved by the opposition) yet my castling with the ghost rook was allowed and resurrected the piece.  Such is the fun of chess rules.